# Как заблокировать прямой доступ к директории?

Tags: веб-программирование, java

Как в Java веб проекте можно заблокировать прямой  доступ пользователя к определенной директории или предоставить доступ к определенным директорииям?

Например, здесь

```
project
-Web pages
--config
---config.xml
--views
---index.jsp
---list.jsp
```

пользователь не мог открыть `/project/config/config.xml`  или  `/project/view/index.jsp` непосредсвенно из браузера.

Comment: Альтернативный вариант спрятать эти папки в /WEB-INF/.

Comment: Сервер же полностью в ваших руках, в чём проблема?

Comment: Хотелось бы узнать можно сделать это через web.xml или через настройки Tomcat

Comment: Наверное, так: http://serverfault.com/a/29735 ?

Но лучше, на мой взгляд, положить файлы вне wwwroot.

Comment: А почему нельзя запретить доступ через .htaccess ?

Comment: Можно просто создать скрипт,при обращении к запрещенным файлам,он бы выдавал там страницу с ошибкой,ну лучше не заморачиваться и через  .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью web.xml можно...но насколько я помню спецификация предусматривает использование папки WEB-INF, а это в принципе и есть "сокрытие" Вашего контента.И порядок доступа к этому содержимому и настраивается с помощью web.xml...как-то так.